# how to resolve syntax error after decompiling the .class file

Tags: java, android, exception, decompiling, decompiler

My Problem is that when i decompiled my .class file it show error in catch block and reflecting weird end result here is my code .

```
public void f() {
    try {
        if (this.u == 0) {
            this.h();
        } else {
            this.i();
        }

    } catch (Exception var2) {
        throw var2;       // exception occur here
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use printStackTrace method instead of throw.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay actually in catch block there is a syntax error so it suggested to add try catch block for this throw exception under catch block. would you please explain why Decompiler showing this syntax error.

Comment: @IrshadKhan - Where is the closing brace of your catch block?.. Either  your catch block o your function doesn't have a closing brace..

Comment: I dont see throws statement with method defination(as `Exception` is a checked exception), I assume its may not be decompiled properly.

Comment: please see the function i gave to you at answer!! you have not formatted with braces correctly

Comment: @TheLostMind sorry i forgot to add the braces now i edit my question. I have the question for all Guys that why Decompiler shows this major syntax error which is not possible in real time case when we code.

Comment: please have a stack trace and work accordingly!!

Comment: ... use a better decompiler.

Comment: @Antimony please suggest me some good Decompiler Except AndroChef, Cavaj, jd-jui

Comment: @Irshad - Procyon is the best I know of.

Comment: @Antimony  would you please explain me how to use Procyon????

Comment: Procyon is a command-line decompiler.  There are some usage examples on the website.  There are also two GUI front-ends built atop Procyon: [SecureTeam](http://secureteam.net/Java-Decompiler.aspx) and [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten), but they tend to lag behind the command line version.

Answer (score 2):

write this function as

```
    public void f() throws Exception {
          try {
             if(u == 0) {
                this.h();
             } else {
                this.i();
             }

          } catch (Exception var2) {

                throw var2;       // exception occur here


       }
}
```

and catch the exception where you are calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with throw statement.
to resolve this

**Option 1**

```
public void f() throws Exception
```

add throw statement with your function declaration.

**Option 2**

```
try {
    throw var2; // exception occur here
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something
}
```

catch this throw exception.

Answer (score -1):

i just replace below line

```
throw var2;
```

with

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

now it works properly and i use the "Easy To java Source Converter" decompiler for my decompilation process.

Thanks To All!!!